# TypeError: cookies is not iterable (Next.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, cookies, next.js

I wanted to set a cookie in Next.js 13 from a `route.ts`.

I tried many different ways but end up with the same error.

Here's one way using the in which I followed the Next.js documentation on [setting a cookie](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options) using the `cookies` library provided by Next.js:

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const token = "asdfasdf";

  cookies().set("token", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    sameSite: "strict",
    path: "/",
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
  });

  return NextResponse.json(
    {},
    {
      status: 200,
    }
  );
}
```

I also tried setting the cookie from the headers option when returning the response:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { serialize } from "cookie";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const token = "asdfasdf";

  const serialized = serialize("token", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    sameSite: "strict",
    path: "/",
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
  });

  return NextResponse.json(
    {},
    {
      status: 200,
      headers: { "Set-Cookie": serialized },
    }
  );
}
```

And also a few other ways, but it all gives this 500 (Internal Server) error:

```
TypeError: cookies is not iterable
    at get [headers map sorted] (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1844:34)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1865:43
    at Headers Iterator.next (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1108:26)
    at toNodeOutgoingHttpHeaders (/Users/luqmanmalik/Documents/Web Projects/Next/alternata-book-web/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/utils.js:106:31)
    at invokeRender (/Users/luqmanmalik/Documents/Web Projects/Next/alternata-book-web/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:275:122)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async handleRequest (/Users/luqmanmalik/Documents/Web Projects/Next/alternata-book-web/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:447:24)
    at async requestHandler (/Users/luqmanmalik/Documents/Web Projects/Next/alternata-book-web/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:464:13)
    at async Server.<anonymous> (/Users/luqmanmalik/Documents/Web Projects/Next/alternata-book-web/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:117:13)
```

Comment: As per the NextJS documentation: "This cookies instance is read-only. To set cookies, you need to return a new Response using the `Set-Cookie` header." This is what you have done in your second implementation and it should work. (I tested it locally and it does.)

May I know what version of NextJS and Node you are using?

Comment: @SamyRahmani I use NextJS 13.4.19 and Node v18.14.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Node V18.14.1, see this [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/46704). Please consider upgrading your node version.

Answer (score 0):

I just Upgraded my node version from 18.13.0 to 18.18.0
Using nvm following [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-switch-node-js-versions-nvm/) and [this one](https://itslinuxfoss.com/fix-command-not-found-nvm/) for the nvm installation.
nvm helps you to upgrade to a higher version of node

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm too updating the Node version fixed the issue. Nvm is very useful btw

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35151522)